# Unable to create ArrayList from few items and connect them to some features through a listener

Tags: java, arrays, swing, arraylist

I made a GUI in Eclipse:

```
ArrayList<Slovo> slovoList;
JFrame frame;
private JTextField textOkno1;
private JTextField preklad1;
private JTextField spravne1;
private JTextField textOkno2;
private JTextField preklad2;
private JTextField spravne2;
```

If needed I will answer all questions in comments if possible, but please try to be patient with me and help put me out of my few days of misery.

```
private JButton btnNewButton_1;
private JButton btnNewButton;
 public Slovnik() {
    initialize();
}
```

This is all done in Eclipse

```
public void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 544, 452);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    textOkno1 = new JTextField();
    textOkno1.setBounds(37, 11, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textOkno1);
    textOkno1.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("");
```

Here I do initialization of the listener, but I don't do declaration because my ArrayList isn't cooperating here. Maybe I should do it in another part of the code?

```
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener1());
    btnNewButton.setBounds(8, 362, 115, 41);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
    preklad1 = new JTextField();
    preklad1.setBounds(163, 11, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(preklad1);
    preklad1.setColumns(10);

    spravne1 = new JTextField();
    spravne1.setBounds(292, 11, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(spravne1);
    spravne1.setColumns(10);

    textOkno2 = new JTextField();
    textOkno2.setBounds(37, 55, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textOkno2);
    textOkno2.setColumns(10);

    preklad2 = new JTextField();
    preklad2.setBounds(163, 55, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(preklad2);
    preklad2.setColumns(10);

    spravne2 = new JTextField();
    spravne2.setBounds(292, 55, 86, 20);
    frame.getContentPane().add(spravne2);
    spravne2.setColumns(10);



    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("");

    btnNewButton_1.setBounds(163, 353, 131, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);



    JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("");
    btnNewButton_2.setBounds(318, 353, 200, 50);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_2);
}
```

So, one more time. I'm a total novice so I don't know how I should do this. When I want to use instance field within a static context. Is this my whole problem?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Slovnik window = new Slovnik();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Here I have an ArrayList but my listeners under the main method can't see the this.

```
    ArrayList<Slovo> slovoList = new ArrayList<Slovo>();
    Slovo wien = new Slovo("vieden", "wien");
    slovoList.add(wien);
    Slovo hunt = new Slovo("pes", "hunt");
    slovoList.add(hunt);
    Slovo junge = new Slovo("chlapec", "junge");
    slovoList.add(junge);
    Slovo jetz = new Slovo("teraz", "jetz");
```

I want to call objects with the list.get() method so they can be shuffled.

```
    Collections.shuffle(slovoList);
}
```

Here is the listener. I want to call a method after I click the button and set the text in the TextField.

```
class ActionListener1 implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        textOkno2.setText(slovolist.get(i).getPreklad());
    }
}
```

}

I made the GUI in eclipse. I don't know which part of the code should be where to make everything work properly.

This is the Slovo class:

```
public class Slovo {

public  String preklad;  public String meno;


public Slovo(String preklad , String meno ) {
    this.preklad = preklad;
    this.meno = meno ;

    }




public  String getPreklad() {
return preklad;
}


public String getMeno() {
return meno ;
}

public void setPreklad(String preklad){
    this.preklad = preklad;
}
```

Comment: There may be a language issue here, but your question is not clear to me at all. Could you please post more details about your problem, what you're trying to do, what you're not able to do,...

Comment: sorry my english is really bad, soo i wanna do some one way distionary soo i make class "words" here i have objects, some lets say german words and i do them with constructor with theyr original name and then in english. and second party is this class when i wanna do it function with some gui soo i wanna after clicking button fill textfield with this english eqiwalent soo its second string in my constructor of object word. but im not able use it in array of word objects and then call object with listener and fill afeer that this text arena...i dont know if i made it clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, let me be clear that I have no idea what you're asking. As such, I'm only able to provide correctly structured code and a few explanations which will very likely solve your problem.

- Your fields were declared outside of your class.
- You didn't have the proper "class" modifier.
- Your main method was declared outside of your class.
- You declared an instance method "initialize" outside of your class.
- You initialized your fields in an "initialize" method that was never called.
- You didn't make proper use of class constructors for initialization.

Keep in mind that these are corrections to the structure of your code, not the syntax or method calls or any other issues you might have had...which was likely caused by the incorrect structure.

All I can tell you is, *SLOW DOWN*. You should focus on learning basic syntax, class structure, various modifier keywords and a number of other things before ever attempting to write a GUI application.

```
      // This is a class, use the appropriate modifier.
     public class Slovnik() {
        // Field declarations should be made within the class, not outside of it.
        ArrayList<Slovo> slovoList;
        JFrame frame;
        private JTextField textOkno1;
        private JTextField preklad1;
        private JTextField spravne1;
        private JTextField textOkno2;
        private JTextField preklad2;
        private JTextField spravne2;

        private JButton btnNewButton_1;
        private JButton btnNewButton;

        ArrayList<Slovo> slovoList = new ArrayList<Slovo>();

        private class ActionListener1 implements ActionListener {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                System.out.println(jetz.getPreklad());
            }
        }

        // Initialize your fields in the constructor.
        public Slovnik() {
            frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setBounds(100, 100, 544, 452);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
            textOkno1 = new JTextField();
            textOkno1.setBounds(37, 11, 86, 20);
            frame.getContentPane().add(textOkno1);
            textOkno1.setColumns(10);

            JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("");
            btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener1());
            btnNewButton.setBounds(8, 362, 115, 41);
            frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
            preklad1 = new JTextField();
            preklad1.setBounds(163, 11, 86, 20);
            frame.getContentPane().add(preklad1);
            preklad1.setColumns(10);

            spravne1 = new JTextField();
            spravne1.setBounds(292, 11, 86, 20);
            frame.getContentPane().add(spravne1);
            spravne1.setColumns(10);

            textOkno2 = new JTextField();
            textOkno2.setBounds(37, 55, 86, 20);
            frame.getContentPane().add(textOkno2);
            textOkno2.setColumns(10);

            preklad2 = new JTextField();
            preklad2.setBounds(163, 55, 86, 20);
            frame.getContentPane().add(preklad2);
            preklad2.setColumns(10);

            spravne2 = new JTextField();
            spravne2.setBounds(292, 55, 86, 20);
            frame.getContentPane().add(spravne2);
            spravne2.setColumns(10);



            JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("");

            btnNewButton_1.setBounds(163, 353, 131, 50);
            frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);



            JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("");
            btnNewButton_2.setBounds(318, 353, 200, 50);
            frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_2);

            Slovo wien = new Slovo("vieden", "wien");
            slovoList.add(wien);
            Slovo hunt = new Slovo("pes", "hunt");
            slovoList.add(hunt);
            Slovo junge = new Slovo("chlapec", "junge");
            slovoList.add(junge);
            Slovo jetz = new Slovo("teraz", "jetz");
            Collections.shuffle(slovoList);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {    
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Slovnik window = new Slovnik();
                        window.frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });   
        }            
    }
```